# my app keep crashing after tryed to connect it to firebase kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I created a simple login and sup app and connect it to firebase.
so far the logging layout does not even show up it's just crushing while lanching which makes me so confused?
[![eroo message][1]][1]
this is my login/main activity

````
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.buGotosub)




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,SubscribAcc::class.java))
            finish()

        }

    }
    public override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updarUI(currentUser)

    }
    fun updarUI(currentUser : FirebaseUser?){

    }
} ```
````

Comment: Hi, can you help to attach error log and the gradle code as well?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond with @AlexMamo